# Is it correct to say "The app was installed on a couple of devices as a pilot"?

Tags: meaning, phrase-requests

This is what I wanted to write:

```
The app was piloted on a couple of devices.
```

But I really want to use the word "install", so that non-tech people don't wonder "how was it piloted?"

Does `pilot-installed` make sense?

Comment: The sentence in your question title is good.  "pilot-installed" does not make sense and sounds like a pilot (aviator) installed it.

Comment: How formal do you want to be.  Your title sentence is good but just a hair informal, mostly because of the use of "couple", but also in the use of "pilot" as a noun vs verb or adjective.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think the sentence in your question title will convey your meaning to most people. You could improve it by adding: 
"..as a pilot *study*"
or "pilot *program*" to make it clearer.

Alternatively, if you are worried about confusion around the word "pilot" why not use something else altogether, like "trial"?

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest something like "In our pilot testing, the app was installed on a couple of devices."